# Use route pattern by identified with Slim

Tags: php, laravel, get, slim

The following route works fine and the method can loop through the items:
http://localhost/library/api/books

```
$app->get('/api/books', 'Book:getBooks');
```

The class:

```
class Book {
    :
    :
    public function __construct($container) { 
        $this->container = $container; 
    }    

    public function getBooks($request, $response) {
        :
        :
        echo '{"book": ' . json_encode($books) . '}';        
    }

    public function getBook($id) {
        echo json_encode($id); 
    }
}
```

Calling the method with route pattern identified by 'id' as follows, returns nothing (empty $id):
http://localhost/library/api/books/10

```
$app->get('/api/books/{id}', 'Book:getBook');
```

It seems like 'id' won't pass.

How to handle correctly route pattern by identifier?

Comment: Can you the error message, like what the chrome dev console says under console + network, thus I learned to create those routes differently which probably is not the error, but I could still post them if you would like to. Furthermore do you push any button to access each book or do you just open them with the url? If you created a button to show each book post the blade to that button please

Comment: No error messages in console log, I posted here a simple solution that I found.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, please let us know what the dev console says for instance in chrome under the category console and network.

I am not sure why you choose to create your routes like that, but I would create them following way (which also looks more tidy) :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'book'], function ()
{
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'BookController@index']);
    Route::get('new', ['as' => 'new', 'uses' => 'BookController@new']);
    Route::get('show/{bookID}', ['as' => 'show', 'uses' => 'BookController@show']);
    Route::get('edit/{bookID}', ['as' => 'edit', 'uses' => 'BookController@edit']);
    Route::post('create', ['as' => 'create', 'uses' => 'BookController@create']);
    Route::post('update', ['as' => 'update', 'uses' => 'BookController@update']);
    Route::delete('destroy/{deviceID}', ['as' => 'destroy', 'uses' => 'BookController@destroy']);
});
```

The BookController would look like this then:

```
class BookController extends Controller
{
    // this shows all books and adds a pagination of 15 items, which you can easily increase or decrease
    public function index()
    {
        $books = DB::table('books')->paginate(15);
        return view('books.index', compact('books');
    }

    public function new()
    {
        $book = new Book;

        return view('books.new', [
            'books' => $books,
            'type' => 'new'
        ]);
    }

    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, Book::$rules); // I put the rules inside of the Book Model, but you could just add them here aswell

        $data = $request->all();

        $book = new Book();
        $book->fill($data);

        if($book->save())
        {
            return redirect()->route('new')->with('success', 'success.');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->route('new')->with('error', 'Error.')->withInput();
        }

    public function edit(Request $request, $bookID = 0)
    {
        $books    = Book::all();
        $newBook  = new Book;
        $book     = Book::find($bookID);

        if(is_null($book))
        {
            $books = Device::paginate(10); // paginate if you like to
            return view('books.index', [
                'books' => $books,
                'errorNoBook' => 'No BOok'
            ]);
        }
        else
        {
            $bookID = $book->id;
        }

        return view('books.edit', [
            'allBooks' => $allBooks,
            'new' => $new,
            'book' => $book,
        ]);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a simple working solution that I found:

```
:
:
public function getBook($request, $response) {
    $route = $request->getAttribute('route'); // route object
    $id = $route->getArgument('id'); // route object identifier
    $book = $this->db->table('books')->where('id', $id)->first();
    echo json_encode($book); 
}
```